# WWW::Mechanize::Chrome capture XHR response

Tags: perl, google-chrome, www-mechanize

I am using Perl WWW::Mechanize::Chrome to automate a JS heavy website.

In response to a user click the page among many other requests, requests and loads a JSON file using XHR.

Is there some way to save this particular JSON data to a file?

Comment: You can record all requests as [HAR](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/).

Comment: The link speaks of keycodes and clicking on browser elements. I do not think these will be available from  WWW::Mechanize::Chrome :(

Answer (score 0):

To intercept requests like that, you generally need to use the webRequest API to filter and retrieve specific responses. I do not think you can do that via WWW::Mechanize::Chrome.

Comment: A link to the relevant documentation would be quite useful. WWW::Mechanize::Chrome allows you to call API functions in Chrome, so there might be a way to do this. Effectively that's all the module does, so it should also just be a matter of subclassing and adding a call (or creating a PR and contributing).

Answer (score -1):

WWW::Mechanize::Chrome tries to give you the content of all requests, but Chrome itself does not make the content of XHR requests available ( https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457484 ). So the approach I take in (for example ) [Net::Google::Keep](https://github.com/Corion/Net-Google-Keep) is to replay the XHR requests using plain Perl LWP requests by copying the cookies and parameters from the Chrome requests-

Please note that the official support forum for WWW::Mechanize::Chrome is https://perlmonks.org , not StackOverflow.